# Creating Limited HashSet

Tags: java, hashset

So, I'm trying to create limited `HashSet`, so whenever the `LimitedHashSet` exceeds 1024 elements, it throws an `Error`, *don't ask, instructions*.
Here's my code so far,

```
import java.util.HashSet;
public class LimitedHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E>{
    public LimitedHashSet(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return super.size();
    }

    private class LimitedHashSetError{
        LimitedHashSetError(){
            if (size() > 1024){
                throw new Error("LimitedHashSetError");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            LimitedHashSet<Integer> lhs = new LimitedHashSet<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1026 ; i++) {
                lhs.add(i);
            }
        }
}
```

However, nothing happens.

Comment: How is your class `LimitedHashSetError` should work? It is not used anywhere

Comment: @ByeBye behaves like normal `HashSet`, except it has limited amount of elements.

Comment: You're just calling `add(i)` 1026 times.  Where should it check the limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never instantiate `LimitedHashSetError` so you never check the size. I would prefer a check-method which will be invoked after every `add(All)`:

```
public class LimitedHashSet<E> extends HashSet<E>{

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        boolean result = super.add(e);
        checkSize();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        boolean result = super.addAll(c);
        checkSize();
        return result;
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        if (size() > 1024){
            throw new Error("LimitedHashSetError");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not valid, because you check size after adding -> if you catch error your set will be in wrong state

Comment: I was wondering this, but the "spec" doesn't specify whether the extra elements should *not* be added.  The elements have to be added for the size to exceed the limit.

Comment: @ByeBye In that case you need to check if the value to add is already in your set or you will get an error if your set holds the values from 1 to 1024 and you add 1

Answer (score 1):

you should do:

```
@Override
public boolean add(E e) {
    boolean x = super.add(e);
    if (size() > 1024) {
        throw new Error("Limited Hash Set Error");
    }
    return x;
}

@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean x = super.addAll(c);
    if (size() > 1024) {
        throw new Error("LimitedHashSetError");
    }
    return x;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override two methods `addAll` and `add` in your class:

```
@Override
public boolean addAll(final Collection<? extends E> c) {
    boolean a = true;
    for(final E e: c) {
        a = a && add(e);
    }
    return a;
}

@Override
public boolean add(final E e) {
    if (size() + 1 > 1024 && !contains(e)){
        throw new Error("LimitedHashSetError");
    }
    return super.add(e);
}
```

Comment: As described in my answer you'll get an error if your set holds 1024 elements and you add an existing element.

Comment: I think the `add()` is still wrong; it's checking before the elements are (potentially) added.

Comment: I think you need something like `if (size() + 1 > 1024 && !contains(e))`